# moodle invalid response after successful userlogin

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

i was facing issue in moodle user was not able to logged in so i change the DB collation and user is now able to login into dashboard but i am also getting this error.

[image: le]

Now user is able to login but this popup error is coming.

```
invalidresponse
Invalid response value detected
File: /lib/externallib.php
Line: 425
Stack trace:
Error in response - Missing following required key in a single structure: tourconfig
Error code: invalidresponse
* line 425 of /lib/externallib.php: invalid_response_exception thrown
* line 250 of /lib/externallib.php: call to external_api::clean_returnvalue()
* line 59 of /lib/ajax/service.php: call to external_api::call_external_function()
```

Comment: Have you tried to purge Moodle cache? `php admin/cli/purge_caches.php`

Comment: Now it's working thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, user was not able to login into `Moodle` and it was the `dmlwrite exception`. So i changed the DB collation of user table and it's started throwing an error after user logged in.

We are running this whole setup on digital ocean and due to some issue in CPU & Memory, i recycle my whole kubernetes cluster and error resolve automatically.

So as @adrian-sărmaș suggested clear cache and give it try for me maybe it was only issue of caching.